# Element type "uses-permission" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"

Tags: java, android

I want to make an android site application on Webview, but there is an error I can't find it
Element type "uses-permission" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"</uses-permission>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Flyregalis">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You a missing a closing >. Use:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the XML `<uses-permission>` nodes have to be closed like this `>` or like this `/>`

Swapping your line for this one will fix it:

```xml
<!-- Note that you did not close the opening XML tag -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" <-- here !! -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```